# get meeting details of a user from MS Teams through Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, ms-flow

I want to make a flow which gets the meeting details of a user in a day. There are some requirements:

1. meeting time (start to end)
2. free time between the meetings

- for example a user have a meeting from 2:00pm to 3:00pm and 5:00pm to 6:00pm , the user will be free from 4:00pm to 5:00pm, after 6:00pm  and before 3:00pm.

Can someone tell  me how can I make the flow?